# Polarisation directions in standing waves in cubical cavity

Tags: statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation

I was studying Rayleigh-Jean's formula. The author has assumed a cubical cavity of each side $L$ with perfectly reflecting surfaces. According to author, there are two perpendicular directions of polarization for a standing wave taken in arbitrary direction. I am stuck up here, my question is why two directions of polarization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible because there are two linearly-independent solutions for wave-equation of the light traveling in the direction $\vec n$. Let $\vec n$ coincides with z axis then there are two polarizations for $\vec E$: x- and y-. Every wave of light traveling along z axis may be seen as superposition of two waves with x- and y- polarizations.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation with your problem. I think the condition for describing the electromagnetic field into polarization modes is the transverse property which sated the vector potential is perpendicular with the propagation ($k\cdot A=0$). 
In my calculation, (in Coulomb gauge) from the explicit form for an electrical field such as eqs. (53–55) from this document (http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~awolski/Teaching/Cockcroft/EMTheory/Electromagnetism-Lecture2.pdf), we only derive the property: $\nabla \cdot A =0$ but I could not find the equation, $k\cdot A =0$.
 Therefore, in my opinion, I think it is impossible to derive polarization modes in this case. Because the vector potential does not perpendicular with the wave propagator.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. Unfortunately, I have many comments (1) If you write an answer to a question ask around 2012, you should try to add something valuable. Especially, if there exists an accepted answer. I don't see that in your answer. (2) Please try to use Mathjax. This provides a latex like formatting. Simply use the dollar signs to "frame" an equation.

Answer (score -1):

I had a huge problem with this question last winter, and I absolutley could not come up a reasonable way of fitting in two directions of polarization. In fact, I could not fit a standing wave into a cubical cavity without having the polarization  varying eveywhere. I came up with a pattern that seemed to work, but it gave me a multiplicity of 3 orientations. I am sure the pattern is right, but there is no factor of 3 in the Rayleigh-Jeans formula, so I just don't get it. Here is the pattern I came up with:

[image: Rectangular Standing Wave Modes]

The green lines are the electric fields, which must be either perpendicular (two walls) or null (third wall) to the boundaries. The pink lines are the magnetic fields which can be parallel to the walls. You can set up this pattern, as far as I can see, in three different orientations: but in the formula for counting the modes, there is no factor of three:

[image: (From the hyperphysics web page)]

I discuss this problem in more detail in my blogpost, ["Counting Modes"](http://marty-green.blogspot.com/2011/02/counting-modes.html).